# Qt:Overload QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, overloading, qcombobox

I want to overload QComboBox to meet my needs, but I don’t know which member functions should be overloaded and how to implement

The specific requirements are as follows:

1. Hide the text box of the QComboBox, change the style of the drop-down button, in general, make it look like a QPushButton
2. Turn the drop-down box into a table

such as:

[image]

Comment: Why you need combo box for that (and if you need . It have data model and delegate support which can be responsible for this). Qt isn't MFC (WFC) too work solely by overloads. But in in this case it looks like pushbutton that shows menu on the click() signal..

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie If I use the menu, can the menu be a table type? And the menu needs to be next to the button. I don't know how to achieve this. Can you tell me in detail? Thanks

Comment: You'd probably be better off using an actual QPushButton, along with a custom dialog that shows up in the appropriate location in response to its `clicked()` siganl.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner custom dialog or menu? Which one is better

Comment: AFAIK menus in Qt are always a single vertical column (with optional submenus) so if you really want a multi column table layout, I think writing a custom dialog with a QGridLayout would be easier than trying to hack QMenu into doing something it wasn’t designed to do.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner thanks, i got it